# $\forall x\in \mathbb{R} \exists b\in (x, x+a) \frac{f'(x) } {f(x) }=e^{a{f'(b) }/{f(b) } }$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity

Let $a\ge 0$ and $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow  \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable positive function such that $f'(x) =f(x+a) \forall x\in \mathbb{R}$. How can I prove that $\forall x\in \mathbb{R} \exists b\in (x, a+x) \frac{f'(x) } {f(x) }=e^{a\frac{f'(b) }{f(b) } }$. I tried the intermediate value Theorem but couldn't prove it. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: What is the context for this problem, i.e. where did you come across it? It might be helpful to read up on [delay differential equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delay_differential_equation).

Comment: @Theo It's the first question of an exercise given to us by our Real Analysis teacher. Thank you for the reference.

Comment: Eww, that's a bit nasty. I'm aware that delay differential equations are connected somewhat with the Lambert W function, but I guess if this is an entry-level question in a real analysis course, then you won't be familiar with such tools. Which theorems are you familiar with? You know IVT, but what about the other value theorems (extreme and mean)? How about Fermat's theorem about stationary points? I don't see a solution myself, but it would be good to know which tools you can use.

Comment: @Theo I'm familiar with the mean and extreme value theorems but never heard of Fermat's Theorem about stationary points. Actually I welcome any solution you can come up with. If you have to use heavy machinery then let it be, don't worry about it :)

Comment: If you define $g(x) = \log (f(x)) $, then your identity is equivalent to $$ \frac{d}{dx} g(x) = \exp\left(a \frac{d}{dt} g(t)\bigg|_{t=b}\right). $$ You might then be able to use the fact that $$\exp\left(\alpha\frac{d}{dx} h(x)\right) = h(x+\alpha). $$ Maybe coupling this with one of your theorems and the identity $f'(x) = f(x+a) $ will get you there.

Comment: @Cameron what exactly is $h$ ?

Comment: @Omer, $b$ depends on $x$, so for two different real numbers $x_1$ and $x_2$ there are two b's which are not necessarily equal.

Comment: @Omer, you're welcome!

Comment: if you write $\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=\frac{f(x+a)}{f(x)}$, your conclusion is just the intermediate value theorem of $\ln f(x)$ but on the interval $(x,x+a)$, not $(a,x)$

Comment: Of course, you could remove the words "such that" and replace the words "there exists" with the symbol $\exists$ in both the title and the question without changing the meaning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define a new function $g(x)=\ln{\big(f(x)\big)}$. We note that $0<f(x)$ so $g$ is well defined as a composition. Furthermore, $g$ is continuous on any interval of the form $[x,x+a]$ and differentiable on any interval of the form $(x,x+a)$, and so $g$ satisfies the conditions for the [Mean Value Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem), that is: There exist $b\in(x,x+a)$ that satisfies:
$$g'(b )=\frac{g(x+a)-g(x)}{(x+a)-x}=\frac{g(x+a)-g(x)}{a}\Longrightarrow(*)\space\space\space ag'(b)=g(x+a)-g(x)$$

We now take care of the LHS of $(*)$:
$$ag'(b)=a\cdot\frac{d}{dx}\ln{f(x)}\bigg|_{x=b}=a\frac{f'(b)}{f(b)}$$

And now the RHS of $(*)$:
$$g(x+a)-g(x)=\ln{f(x+a)}-\ln{f(x)}=\ln{\frac{f(x+a)}{f(x)}}=\ln{\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}}$$

The second equality is from $\ln$ properties and the last equality is from the given relation $f'(x)=f(x+a)$. So we now substitute what we found back to $(*)$ to get:

$$a\frac{f'(b)}{f(b)}=\ln{\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}}\Longrightarrow e^{a{f'(b)}/{f(b)}}=\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}$$

And that settles the proof.

Comment: I indeed made a mistake while writing the question, it should be $(x,a+x)$ instead of $(a,x)$ (I'm so sorry!). Thank you for the answer Omer!